# Outlook inbox rule to get attachments' filename without actually downloading the attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment, rule

I'm trying to set up an incoming rule to get the attachments' filename and write them to excel automatically without having to download the attachments itself. Is there anyway to do this with POP3 or IMAP in Outlook VBA?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Item.Attachements(1).FileName
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachment-filename-property-outlook

Comment: This only works with downloaded attachments. I don't want to download them because  I have thousands of mails everyday and can't take the time to download them all and it would also be bad for my HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Try The code below .. It helps you to go through your inbox folder and get every attachment filename ..

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Attachments
    Dim myitem As Folder
    Dim myItemI As Object
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Your Inbox folder
    Set myitem = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Loop through all mails in Inbox Folder
    For i = 1 To myitem.Items.Count
        'Get the mail number i
        Set myItemI = myitem.Items(i)
        'Get the attachments of the mail number i
        Set a = myItemI.Attachments
        ' if the mail contains attachments
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            'Go through and display each attachment filename
            For j = 1 To myItemI.Attachments.Count
              MsgBox myItemI.Attachments.Item(j).DisplayName
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This seem to only work with read mail (mail attachment already downloaded). Is there anyway for it to work with all mail?

Comment: Are you sue ? .. for me it works with all mails, read and unread ones ..

Comment: I tried for my inbox and I was only able to get the name of read mail's attachment. For the unread mail's ones the attachment item count returned 0 and I could not get the name. BTW I'm using Outlook 2010 and IMAP.